Keep only Date value in an array
I've got an initial array mixing dates, text and  blank values. My aim is to get an array with only dates. I've tried that but it's not working, no value is recognised as a date... Could you help me please?
function fil () {

var initialArray = [ '10 April 2024',
  '{AS} BG AV (5€, Return of Capital)',
  '{SW} FABG SS (0.45sek, Regular Cash), INDT SS (2.85sek, Regular Cash)',
  '',
  '11 April 2024',
  '{DE} ROCKB DC (43dkk, Regular Cash)' ];


    //Today's date
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var Today = new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0);
    
    
    var Tomorrow = new Date(Today.getFullYear(),Today.getMonth(),(Today.getDate()+1))
    

    const filteredArray = initialArray.map(d=>Tomorrow - d).filter(v=>v>0);
    const minIndex = filteredArray.indexOf(Math.min(...filteredArray))+1;
    const minDate = filteredArray[minIndex];
    
    console.log(new Date (filteredArray)); // Invalid Date in the console
    console.log(minDate); // undefined in the console
    console.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(minDate),"GMT+2","dd-MM-yyyy")); // 01-01-1970 in the console
    
    }


This will filter the array down to only the strings that can successfully be parsed as Dates in javascript.   This works because anything that can't be parsed will return NaN, which is a falsy value:


let onlyDates = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter(d => Date.parse(d))
}

let initialArray = ['10 April 2024',
  '{AS} BG AV (5€, Return of Capital)',
  '{SW} FABG SS (0.45sek, Regular Cash), INDT SS (2.85sek, Regular Cash)',
  '',
  '11 April 2024',
  '{DE} ROCKB DC (43dkk, Regular Cash)'
];

console.log(onlyDates(initialArray))



